# How to delete a document locally so the server retains the copy in couches server

Tags: android, ios, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I have succuessfully implemented an application using Couchbase Server, Couchbase Lite (iOS and Android) and Couchbase Sync Gateway.

A module in the application sync certain documents every 3 minutes. 
Now, the challenge is to retain only the last 1 week's document on the device.

However, the Couchbase server should retain all the documents.

Deleting the document in Couchbase lite results in deletion from the server as well. 
Here is the excerpt from Couchbase site

> Deleting a document actually just creates a new revision (informally called a "tombstone") that  has the special _deleted property set to true. This ensures that the deletion will replicate to the server, and then to other clients that pull from that database, just like any other document revision.

Appreciate help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sync gateway's [channel functionality](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/sync-gateway/channels/index.html). So the devices would only sync documents that have been assigned to the channel named let's say "lastweek". You can define the channel to be a [sync function](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/sync-gateway/channels/developing/index.html#using-a-sync-function) that looks at the created field on your document (assuming you are keeping track of when the document was created)